# Visual Studio Cordova - won't deploy iOS app

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I have a simple VS Cordova app, running VS on my PC with an iPhone connected.

I've setup remote build agent, and that's all fine - the app builds and appears in the bin/iOS/debug folder (when I choose Local Device)

However, it never deploys. It says "deploy started", and just stays like that forever. I expect at this point the app should appear in iTunes on the PC?

Comment: can you able to get the ipa in bin--> ios-->debug folder

Answer (score -1):

You need an active Apple ID associated with an Apple Developer Program membership in order to deploy to an "Actual Device".

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW1